# Low side Current sensor design

Tags: current, amplifier, measurement, current-measurement

I need a suggestion on a good amplifier design for a current sensor. The requirement is: 
Operating voltage between 2.7 to 6.0V
Able to output 3.3V when a 10A current is flowing through sensing resistor (maybe 0.011 ohm).
Able to output 1.65V when 5A and so on.
Able to output 0V when 0A.

Is this possible without a -Vs?

My source will be at ~30V

(It would be nice if it could handle voltages as low as 0.4V and current 3A also)

Comment: Surely you mean 'able to output 1.65V when **5A** and.." In other words a voltage directly proportional to current.

Comment: I can suggest ZXCT1009, MCP6H01 or MAX4172 IC for high side current sensing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a high side current shunt solution would eliminate the need for a -Vs supply. Also, it is simpler to fine-tune the output to full-scale in a separate voltage gain stage, taking its input from the current shunt stage.

For example, using the Texas Instruments [INA193 current shunt monitor](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina193.pdf):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOVjAj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The nice thing about the INA193 is, with its common mode range being -18 to +80 Volts, it can be used as a **low-side current shunt monitor as well**, by switching the sense pins around and changing the shunt location, and not touching the rest of the circuit. It allows its output to reach not just the ground rail, but 0.3 Volts below it, without a -Vs pull-down.

INA193 has a fixed gain of 20 V/V. Thus, a 0.01 Ohm shunt resistor will provide an output range of 0 to 2.0 Volts.

The preset `Rtrim` shown in the schematic can be adjusted to give an output of precisely 3.3 Volts on full-scale (10 Amperes) reading.

Trimming the gain might be a good idea anyway, since a small imprecision in the shunt resistor would result in significant variation in full-scale output from the InAmp.

---

**Note:** 3.3 Volt output with operating voltage below 3.3 Volts is not feasible with this design: The maximum output will be limited by the Vcc supplied.

If a 3.3 Volt output at 2.7 Volt input is truly required, then an additional charge pump or boost solution would be required to raise the supply voltage of the [TLV2372](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv2372.pdf) to a minimum of 3.3 Volts.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this: -

[image]

The only thing that you may have a bone about is the minimum output limit of 60mV which, on the circuit above, corresponds to a measured current of 30mA. The device will work down to 2.3V on the supply.

If you want 10A full scale, you'd make the sense resistor 0.01 ohms and you'd have an offset equivalent of 300mA i.e. anything smaller than 300mA is hidden.

Your constraints of no negative supply and ability to output a meaningful voltage at 0A is problematic if you take 0A to mean 0.0A. As it stands, the circuit above having a dead spot of 300mA mathematically meets your requirements.

Should you in fact mean 0mA then you might consider producing a -0.5V rail to power the op-amps -Vs connection.

Other useful info on high-side and low-side monitoring can be found [here](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an105.pdf)